# c#-combining two forms

Tags: c#

I want to combine two forms as  in the image i have attached.I am able to do the two forms (login form and application form seperately)right now I am not able to make application form to appear in the background of the login form.this is my screen i what.there is any command specific to make the two form combine as in the screen.Please help me.Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Isn't that called MFC or MCF or whatever the heck that thing is? +1 to OP for making my brain think today

Comment: MDI (Multiple Document Interface, or More Dumb Ideas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a [modal dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28VS.71%29.aspx), from your application form you can try

```
using(LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm())
{
    loginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    DialogResult dialogResult = loginForm.ShowDialog(this); 

    if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Using *using* is a pretty hard requirement for dialogs.  Help out the OP by using the ShowDialog(owner) overload and the Form.StartPosition property.